# Getting dynamic content with jQuery and Masonry infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry

I'm implementing a infinite scroll with jQuery Masonery :

> $(function(){
>
> ```
> var $container = $('#container');
>
> $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
>   $container.masonry({
>     itemSelector: '.box',
>     columnWidth: 100
>   });
> });
>
> $container.infinitescroll({
>   navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
>   nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
>   itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
>   loading: {
>       finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
>       img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
>     }
>   },
>   // trigger Masonry as a callback
>   function( newElements ) {
>     // hide new items while they are loading
>     var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
>     // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
>     $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
>       // show elems now they're ready
>       $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
>       $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
>     });
>   }
> );
>    });
> ```

That is the simplest example, but I am wondering if it is possible to get a dynamic content with AJAX, and not only static pages as show in example :

```
<nav id="page-nav">
  <a href="../pages/2.html"></a>
</nav>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It is Very simple. Please follow below steps.

Change Navigation Link:

```
<nav id="page-nav">
  <a href="../pages/AjaxSource.php?no=2"></a>
</nav>
```

Your AjaxSource.php should be like this

```
<?php 
$pageNo= $_GET['no'];
?>

<?php if ($pageNo==2){?>

<div id="container" class="transitions-enabled clearfix">

    <div class="box photo col3">
      <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/nemoorange/5013039951/" title="Stanley by Dave DeSandro, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039951_3a47ccd509.jpg" alt="Stanley" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="box photo col3">
      <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/nemoorange/5013039951/" title="Stanley by Dave DeSandro, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039951_3a47ccd509.jpg" alt="Stanley" /></a>
    </div>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```